# How to Image scroll in Horizontally after click on next button in iOS

Tags: ios, scroll, gallery

In my application I want to create an image gallery. So I used REPagedScrollView. I able to scroll image on scrolling. But I'm unable to change image when I click on next and previous button. So how do I achieve this functionality?
Multiple image change after scrolling, its work perfectly. 
I tried below code to change image after click on next button.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    scrollView = [[REPagedScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.slider_view.bounds];
    scrollView.delegate=self;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView1
{
    if(scrollView1.tag ==0){
        CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView1.frame.size.width;
        current_page = floor((scrollView1.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2.0) / pageWidth) + 1;
        self.index_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d of %lu",current_page+1,(unsigned long)[self.seletedfile count]];
    }
}
-(IBAction)nextBtn:(id)sender
{
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next button method just do:

```
[scrollView scrollToPageWithIndex:current_page + 1 animated:YES];
```

Comment: but assign  to which image view how to know

Comment: @Stela it will happen automatically. Just put that in your next button method.

Comment: @Stela thank you :) it's stack overflow etiquette to accept the answer if it's right with the check mark next to an answer. The up votes are for good answers that need praise. It doesn't matter to me but for future reference and for people that are workin hard to earn reputation, it's kind to accept the answer if it's right with the check mark